# Can't access Browswersync External URL

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, browser-sync

I have Broswersync set up for a local project, but when I try to access the external URL on other devices on the same network, I get some form of

> The site took too long

message (depending on the browser).  I suspect it is some network setting, but have no idea where to start looking.

Comment: What did you do to set up browsersync? Can you reach your target with ping? Do other services work in your network?

Comment: The pings time out when I try to reach the External URL from another device on the network.  Here is the code from my webpack.config.js:

`
new BrowserSyncPlugin(
      {
        // browse to http://localhost:3000/ during development
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        proxy: 'http://localhost:8080/'
      },
      // plugin options
      {
        // prevent BrowserSync from reloading the page
        // and let Webpack Dev Server take care of this
        reload: false
      }
    )
`

Comment: If you can't ping your device, then there may be a problem with your firewall or routing.

Answer (score 9):

#### Make sure the IP Browsersync *thinks* is your external IP *actually is* your external IP

I just ran into this problem and opening ports in the firewall did exactly nothing. Running a network scan from my iPad (which was unable to connect to Browsersync on the PC) found my PC listed with a different IP than the one Browsersync stated.

Try the following:

- Log in to your router to inspect IPs of connected devices
- on Windows: run `ipconfig` in the command prompt / console
- on your device that is unable to connect: `ping` your dev machine, or if the device is a phone or tablet, install a network scanner app (search for 'ping' in the store)

Doing all of the above confirmed: Browsersync was grabbing the IP of some **VirtualBox** network adapter instead of the **LAN/WiFi adapter**.

Browsersync *thinks* 192.168.**95.1** is my WiFi IP...

[image: Browsersync thinks 192.168.95.1 is my WiFi IP...]

...when in fact that is the IP of some VirtualBox network adapter...

[image: ...when in fact it is 192.168.178.35]

...and the real WiFi IP is is 192.168.**178.35**

### Solution

✅ Connecting to the IP of the LAN/WiFi adapter (still with port :3000) fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks Robro, after days of searching this actually resolved my issue.

Comment: Thank you! After weeks of not being able to connect my phones to the dev site, your answer got me up and running.  So grateful, thank you!

Comment: The perfect answer worked like a charm.